# How do i repeat this code

Tags: python, loops, csv, repeat

```
while True:
import csv  #Creates a CSV file
name = input("Hello what is your name?")
print("Hello",name,"!")
opinion = input ("How do you feel about the Icentre A. Good B. Amazing C. I don't like it      Please type your answer here -->")
if opinion == 'Good'or opinion == 'good' or opinion == 'A' or opinion == 'a':
    print("Thanks!")
    improvements = input("Anything we can improve?")
    print("Thanks for your feedback!")
    reason = ""
elif opinion == 'Amazing' or opinion == 'amazing'or opinion == 'B' or opinion == 'b':
    print("Thats awesome!")
    improvements = input("Anything we can improve?")
    print("Thanks for your feedback!")
    reason = ""
elif opinion == 'I dont like it' or opinion == 'i dont like it'or opinion == 'C' or opinion == 'c':
    reason = input("Please tell us why -->")
    print("Thank you for your feedback.")
    improvements = ""
results = [ 
       [name,  opinion, improvements, reason]
       ]
                         #w = write,  a = append 
myfile = open("OpenEveningResults.csv", "a", newline="")

mywriter = csv.writer(myfile)
mywriter.writerows(results)
myfile.close()

if name == "stop":
    break
```

It is saying that "break' outside loop". It is an error but i cannot see where i have gone wrong in the code. Not sure if i have indented incorrectly or parted and code that should not be parted.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep hitting F5"? Is this in a web page?

Comment: It would seem that a simple while loop would satisfy this - have you tried this?

Comment: @ceejayoz I mean that i have to keep hitting F5 to re-run the code but I want it to repeat itself.

Comment: @bated I don't know how to do it or where to put any of it. Could you show me or something?

Comment: If this is for a class and you don't know how to do a while loop, you need to either go to class or get a better professor.

Comment: Google is your friend - we are not here to write code for you!

Comment: @ceejayoz This is something I am doing independently but I am doing it for school

Comment: @bated I have been looking on Google but the explanations are either confusing or I dont understand how to change it for what i need

Comment: @ceejayoz I was taught the very basics such as making variables and printing as well as +/- but that was mainly it. I've sat and taught myself the rest with small amounts of help from friends and advice from people.

Comment: You'll need to fix the indentation in the question to *exactly* what you have in (presumably) IDLE. Otherwise it's impossible to reproduce, and we can't help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use indentation for the while loop body as shown below:

```
while True:
    import csv  #Creates a CSV file
    name = input("Hello what is your name?")
    print("Hello",name,"!")
    opinion = input ("How do you feel about the Icentre A. Good B. Amazing C. I don't like it      Please type your answer here -->")
    if opinion == 'Good'or opinion == 'good' or opinion == 'A' or opinion == 'a':
        print("Thanks!")
        improvements = input("Anything we can improve?")
        print("Thanks for your feedback!")
        reason = ""
    elif opinion == 'Amazing' or opinion == 'amazing'or opinion == 'B' or opinion == 'b':
        print("Thats awesome!")
        improvements = input("Anything we can improve?")
        print("Thanks for your feedback!")
        reason = ""
    elif opinion == 'I dont like it' or opinion == 'i dont like it'or opinion == 'C' or opinion == 'c':
        reason = input("Please tell us why -->")
        print("Thank you for your feedback.")
        improvements = ""
    results = [ 
           [name,  opinion, improvements, reason]
           ]
                             #w = write,  a = append 
    myfile = open("OpenEveningResults.csv", "a", newline="")

    mywriter = csv.writer(myfile)
    mywriter.writerows(results)
    myfile.close()

    if name == "stop":
        break
```

Comment: I've done this but it is saying there is an error. which is "break' outside loop"

Comment: Paste your updated code in the question so that we can see what is wrong.

Comment: you need to indent your while loop body as shown above @Dan

Comment: Ah! Okay! Thank you. I've pretty much had to teach myself so I'm still knew but this helps. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`while True:`

Rest of your code goes under here, indented.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to also get the loop to end and have had help from others.